# Angular array remains undefined when passing JSON data

Tags: json, angular, api, undefined

I have an API which returns JSON data about football. The data is then passed to the frontend (angular) but when passing it to the array, the array is still remaining undefined.

JSON Data:

```
match_id":"194200",
"country_id":"41",
"country_name":"England",
"league_id":"148",
"league_name":"Premier League",
"match_date":"2019-04-01",
"match_status":"Finished",
"match_time":"21:00",
"match_hometeam_id":"2617",
"match_hometeam_name":"Arsenal",
"match_hometeam_score":"2 ",
"match_awayteam_name":"Newcastle",
"match_awayteam_id":"2630",
"match_awayteam_score":" 0",
```

This is the angular code to parse the JSON data and put in the array to display:

```
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {

searchFilter: string;
resultArr: FootballModel[];

constructor(private footballService: FootballService, private route: 
ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.footballService.getResults().subscribe(x => this.resultArr = x);
   console.log(this.resultArr);
}
```

When I console.log the x passed in subscribe, the JSON information is returned. So till the x part it is passing well but when it is passing to resultArray and console.log that part, it is returning `undefined`. Wonder if anyone can help.

This is the model:

```
export class FootballModel {
  countryName: string;
  leagueName: string;
  matchDate: string;
  matchHomeTeamName: string;
  matchAwayTeamName: string;
  matchHomeTeamScore: string;
  matchAwayTeamScore: string;
}
```

EDIT: 
Also I am trying to display that data in a table, but somehow it is not showing. Pretty sure it's an easy mistake as well.

```
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let result of results">
    <td>{{result.countryName}}</td>
    <td>{{result.leagueName}}</td>
    <td>{{result.matchDate}}</td>
    <td>{{result.homeTeam}}</td>
    <td>{{result.awayTeam}}</td>
    <td>{{result.homeTeamScore}}</td>
    <td>{{result.awayTeamScore}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http requests return Observable on Angular. Observables has async callback function and you can get data by subscribing it as you did. But when you try to reach data outside of callback function before .subscribe worked at least one time it must be undefined. Because it is writing to the console before your API send response. If you change your ngOnInit function like that it must work.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.footballService.getResults().subscribe(x => {
      this.resultArr = x;
      console.log(this.resultArr);
   });  
}
```

Also check the documentation for [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)

Here is an additional example for this case:

```
ngOnInit() {
   console.log("a");
   this.footballService.getResults().subscribe(x => {
      console.log("c");
      this.resultArr = x;
      console.log(this.resultArr);
   });
   console.log("b");
}
```

Expected result on console is

> "a" "b" "c"

Comment: Was just a stupid mistake. Can't thank you enough :)

Comment: Man you dont have a variable as results. It is "resultArr" in your example and if it is not a solution try to add *ngIf="resultArr" before ngfor. (You can not use ngFor and ngIf together at same html tag. Try to put your ngIf to the parent div or table tag)

Comment: Changed the variable to 'results' since it makes more sense. Tried what you suggested but only table headers are showing.

Comment: Can you see any error on console? or is there any data on your variable which you post to the console?

Comment: No errors on console, and with the solution you posted it seems that data is passing to the 'results' array.

Comment: Okey. Can you create a Stackblitz project to solve your issue. Just put your service, component.ts and html file. We dont need your backend. We can just test it on stackblitz.

Comment: Okay creating it

Comment: Check your attribute names of object on html file. Your class and back-end response are not mapping. After some changes it is working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9yw5zh

Comment: You are completely right. Attributes in html weren't matching with the one coming from JSON. Thank you so much!!